# Behringer UMC1820: arecord does not accept channels parameter

Tags: sound, alsa

I try to record two channels of audio using a Beringer UMC1820 audio interface on Ubuntu 16.04 by invoking

```
arecord -f S32_LE -r 48000 -d 30 -D hw:4,0 -c 2 test.wav
```

but it fails with the message

```
arecord: set_params:1239: Channels count non available
```

It works just fine it I omit the `-c` parameter but in this case an 18 channel file will be created.

The output of `arecord -D hw:4,0 --dump-hw-params` looks as follows:

```
»HW Params« von Gerät "hw:4,0":
--------------------
ACCESS:  MMAP_INTERLEAVED RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  S32_LE
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: 32
FRAME_BITS: 576
CHANNELS: 18
RATE: [44100 96000]
PERIOD_TIME: [125 165103)
PERIOD_SIZE: [6 7281]
PERIOD_BYTES: [432 524232]
PERIODS: [2 1024]
BUFFER_TIME: [125 330227)
BUFFER_SIZE: [12 14563]
BUFFER_BYTES: [864 1048536]
TICK_TIME: ALL
--------------------
arecord: set_params:1233: Sample-Format nicht unterstützt
Available formats:
- S32_LE
```

I also tried using `-plughw:4,0 -c2` as it was suggested [in this thread on Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/alsa/mailman/message/32110962/) instead but the result was an empty stereo file. Stereo recording in e.g. Audacity works just fine but I was looking for a solution to record from the command line.

Is it really the case that only recording all channels ad once is possible or am I missing something?

Comment: This device always provides 18 channels. What exactly should happen with those? Do you want to throw away all but the first two ones?

Comment: I want to record the first two channels as a stereo file, so yes, I want to throw away all but the first two.

Comment: In theory, `-c2` with `plughw` should do what you want. When you run `arecord -r 48000 -f S32_LE -c 18 -d 30 -D hw:4 test.wav`, does the file contain the samples in the correct channels?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of an UMC1820, this command works:

```
arecord -f S32_LE -r 48000 -D hw:4,0 -c 10 test.wav
```

Note that you need 10 channels and all will be recorded, resulting in a WAV file with 10 channels.

If you want to record only the first two channels, this should also work:

```
arecord -f S32_LE -r 48000 -D plughw:4,0 -c 2 test.wav
# playback with
aplay -f S32_LE -r 48000 test.wav
```

Just for the record, the same applies to ecasound if you are into multitracking:

```
ecasound -c -f:32,10,44100 -i alsahw,4,0 -o test.wav
ecasound -c -f:32,2,44100 -i alsaplugin,4,0 -o test.wav
```